# ①の画面でcollectionViewで一覧を表示---> ②選択された画面を削除して①へ戻る時に削除した画面も表示されます。①の画面を最初から処理する方法を教えて戴けませんか?

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, swift4

①の画面でcollectionViewで一覧を表示---> ②選択された画面を削除して①へ戻る時に削除した画面も表示されます。①の画面を最初から処理する方法を教えて戴けませんか?
①と②の画面をsegueでつなぎました。
戻るsegueは上手くいかなかったので接続してみましたが、AppDelegateでエラーになり上手くいきません。

②から戻る時

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backSubViewController",sender: nil)
```

----- この処理の後,delegateエラーになります。

```
// Segue 準備
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     let subVC: SubViewController = (segue.destination as?SubSubViewController)!
     subVC.selectedNo = "eart
}
```

[image: 画面の遷移]

Comment: コード整形する際にコード以外の部分まで洗濯してしまったようで、画像が埋め込まれるべき部分に画像埋め込み用のメタ表記が表示されています。投稿前後に少しご確認いただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 洗濯->選択ですね。今回はこちらで整形し直させていただきましたが、`subVC.selectedNo = "eart`と文法的に間違っている部分はこちらでは元の状態を推測しかねますし、「delegateエラー」と言う言い方も何を表しているのかよくわかりません。何より「①の画面を最初から処理する」と言うのが何を言いたいのか伝わりません。別質問でも「(画面またはviewControllerを)実行する」と言う言葉が使われていましたが、そちらも何を言いたいのかさっぱりわかりませんでした。(コメントをつけて返信をいただいたとしても回答する暇がなかったので、コメントはつけませんでしたが。)画面を制御するviewControllerには様々な処理が記述されているはずなので、単に「実行される」「最初から処理する」と言われてもどの部分のことを表しているのか判然としません。「どんな操作でどんな状態(外部から観察できる事柄)にしたいのか」「実際にはどんな操作でどんなことが起こってしまうのか」をあなたのアプリやコードなどを知らない人にもわかるよう説明することを心がけてください。「何をする」「それに対する結果がこうなる(あるいはこうなって欲しい)」と言うのを、当たり前の部分も省略せずに書き並べるようにすると多くの人に通じやすいかと思います。

Comment: ほか気になった点として、質問タイトルは一目で分かるように簡潔に記述して、詳細を質問文で説明してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segueで次の画面に遷移しているならば、戻るボタンを押したときに

`dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

の1行を呼び出せば戻れると思います。
改めてSegueで遷移する必要はありません。

Comment: 有難う御座いました。上手くいきました。